# How can I identify ranged collector cards?

Tags: rage

I've built a nice deck of cards to play "Rage Frenzy" with, but there is something I found very disturbing.

The distinction between melee and ranged cards is rather important in the context of the mini-game, and I would have expected there to be a way to tell the two apart. I have yet to find a discriminating visual queue to signify that a card is ranged, so I am relying on experience (once I try a card, it's easy to figure out whether it is ranged or not).

Am I missing something, or is there no way to tell if a card is ranged by its appearance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you look at the arrows in the bottom left hand corner there is a distinct difference between melee attacks (solid arrow) and ranged attack (dotted arrow).

Comment: No problem, it's really hard to see the space in between the dashes.